# Creating a backup array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I would like to store `testArray` in `tempArray`, and then erase `testArray`. In the code below `tempArray` gets erased along with `testArray`. Please explain why this isn't working along with a computationally minimal way of achieving this.

```
var testArray = new Array();
testArray.push("green");
alert(testArray.length);//returns one
var tempArray = new Array();
var tempArray = testArray;
alert(tempArray.length);//returns one
testArray.length = 0;
alert(tempArray.length);//returns zero
```

Comment: I have an array of arrays and I want to save one of the sub arrays and empty the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var tempArray = testArray.slice();
```

Creates a copy of the testArray

Answer (score 3):

This is a pass-by-value vs a pass-by-reference issue. When you do

```
var tempArray = testArray;
```

you are creating a *reference* to testArray. Basically tempArray is just another name for the same object. As the other answers point out, what you need is a method like slice() which copies the *data* in testArray.

If you find this confusing you might want to do some research into pass by reference, vs pass by value -- it very much varies language to language. I did a quick google on 'Javascript pass by reference vs pass by value' and found a few articles. For example [this](http://orizens.com/wp/topics/javascript-arrays-passing-by-reference-or-by-value/) looks like it might be a decent place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Your two variable reference the same array, so changing the length of the array using one changes the other. You need to make a copy.

Instead of

```
var tempArray = new Array();
var tempArray = testArray;
```

do

```
var tempArray = testArray.slice(0);
```